# Python: Making a dict from tuple keys with multiple values from a nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

I am new to python and I am trying to make a dictionary using tuples as keys and a nested list as multiple values.

The list is nested in triplets; `[[[Isolation source],[host],[country]]...etc]`

example below:

```
value_list = [[['NaN'], ['sponge'], ['Palau']], [['skin'], ['fish'], ['Cuba']], [['claw'], ['crab'], ['Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']]....]
```

And the tuple of keys;

`key_tuple = ('AB479448', 'AB479449', 'AB602436',...)`

Hence, I would like the output to look like this;

```
dict = {'AB479448': [NaN, sponge, Palau], 'AB479449': [skin, fish, Cuba], 'AB602436': [claw, crab, Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula]
```

I have tried a few different solution but non that I could make work... e.g. dictionary comprehension;

```
dict = { i: value_list for i in key_tuple }
```

The above gives me this (uses the different keys but associates the same value to each of them);

```
{'AB479448': [[[NaN, sponge, Palau]]], 'AB479449': [[[NaN, sponge, Palau]]], 'AB602436': [[[NaN, sponge, Palau]]]...etc..}
```

Would appreciate any pointers... thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, `itertools.izip` (or `zip`) and a dict comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip
>>> value_list = [[['NaN'], ['sponge'], ['Palau']], [['skin'], ['fish'], ['Cuba']], [['claw'], ['crab'], ['Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']]]
>>> key_tuple = ('AB479448', 'AB479449', 'AB602436')
>>> {k: list(chain.from_iterable(v)) for k, v in izip(key_tuple, value_list)}
{'AB479449': ['skin', 'fish', 'Cuba'],
 'AB479448': ['NaN', 'sponge', 'Palau'],
 'AB602436': ['claw', 'crab', 'Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']}
```

Comment: I just copied my answer and switched to browser, I see your answer. aaaahh

Answer (score 1):

Using [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [iter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) you can create your desired output dictionary as follows

```
value_list = [[['NaN'], ['sponge'], ['Palau']], [['skin'], ['fish'], ['Cuba']], [['claw'], ['crab'], ['Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']]]
key_tuple = ('AB479448', 'AB479449', 'AB602436')

dict( (key,[[list(value)]]) for key,value in zip(key_tuple, zip(*(iter(t[0] for v in value_list for t in v),)*3)))

Out[16]: {'AB479448': [[['NaN', 'sponge', 'Palau']]], 'AB479449': [[['skin', 'fish', 'Cuba']]],'AB602436': [[['claw', 'crab', 'Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']]]}
```

if the desired number of element in the list key changes you can substitute the `3` for the new 
length value.

---

It was really fun making this.

Comment: @jO no problem. hcwhsa's answer is far superior, but this was just a fun question. Happy coding :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain
{keys[i]:list(chain.from_iterable(contents)) for i, contents in enumerate(my_list)}
```

This, is equal to:

```
from itertools import chain
for i, contents in enumerate(my_list): #get [['skin'], ['fish'], ['Cuba']]
    result[keys[i]] = list(chain.from_iterable(contents))
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [[['NaN'], ['sponge'], ['Palau']], [['skin'], ['fish'], ['Cuba']], [['claw'], ['crab'], ['Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']]]
>>> keys = ('AB479448', 'AB479449', 'AB602436')
>>> {keys[i]:list(chain.from_iterable(contents)) for i, contents in enumerate(my_list)}
{'AB479449': ['skin', 'fish', 'Cuba'], 'AB479448': ['NaN', 'sponge', 'Palau'], 'AB602436': ['claw', 'crab', 'Japan: Aomori, Natsudomari peninsula']}
>>>
```

Hope this helps!